# why is ICQ not showing image preview when i share my website url?

Tags: images, html, url, sharing, icq

when i share my website on ICQ, it is not showing the image that is specified on the meta tag

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="LJ Aulas">
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Concurso Prefeitura Municipal de Betim-MG: Saiu edital! Nível médio e superior! Até R$ 4.952,00.">
<meta name="Description" content="Número de vagas 392!!!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Número de vagas 392!!!">
<meta name="Robots" content="index, follow">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://ljaulas.com/imagens/thumbs/Design_sem_nome_(20)1.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://ljaulas.com/imagens/thumbs/Design_sem_nome_(20)1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1204">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="304">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://ljaulas.com/posts/noticia/prefeituradebetim">
```

can someone help me?

Comment: To which Source Line of Code are you referring? To which Meta Tag are you referring? To this one: `**<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://ljaulas.com/imagens/thumbs/Design_sem_nome_(20)1.jpg">**`? Are those Double Stars (`**`) meant to be Markers of Comment Lines by any chance?

Comment: the double stars was a mistake, there is no double stars, sorry.

Comment: two quick guesses would be that the parentheses may be causing issues (avoid them in filenames) or that ICQ somehow caches this stuff so it may take some time. do you have any source to prove that ICQ *should* care about this, or that this is the syntax ICQ expects to find?

Comment: all this set of meta tags are used to especify some meta information to be used by othes websites to show an image preview when the site url is shared in some web application, some as facebook feed or chat, twitter, etc. for some reason it is not workin on ICQ

Comment: pzkpfw thank you for the tips